# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handler'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following declaration on my main.py

```
import model
import handler
import helper

import requests
import re
import sys
import os

from time import sleep
from typing import List, Dict, Pattern
from datetime import datetime
```

but, when I try to run my script i get the error: **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handler'
"**

Do I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Have you installed the module? https://pypi.org/project/handler/

Comment: that was the issue, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you did not run this command in terminal in linux or command in windows, then you'd need to explain better, what you need from this module.

COMMAND:

for windows

```
pip install handler
```

for linux

```
pip3 install handler
```